# cannot resolve symbol getFusedLocationProviderClient and LocationCallback

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-gps

I'm a newbie in android programming. I'm trying to get access of a location but this code has an error.

```
getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        // do work here
                        onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
                    }
                },
                Looper.myLooper());
```

I have included `dependencies` in my app `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

What should i import or include to make this methods symbols work? **please help**

Comment: what version of gradle are you using? If it's an old version you need to change `implementation` to `compile`

Comment: @HedeH gradle verson 4.4

Comment: If you don't have static import Then : `getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)` >>> `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext())`

Comment: Ensure you have added classpath to root project `dependencies {        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
}` and don't forget to **clean and build**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace**

> ```
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
>
> getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
> ```

**With**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
```

**Update**

Use this code for requesting Location updates.., **Check this [Github Repo](https://github.com/KhaledLela/GoogleMapV2Test) with complete example.**

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    //**************************
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
    //**************************
    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All mLocation settings are satisfied. The client can initialize mLocation
                    // requests here.
                    enableMyLocation();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MapsActivity.this, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

- **Check out this [article from Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html):**

Comment: here is the error i'm getting when i try to rebuild `error: cannot find symbol method getFusedLocationProviderClient(findme)`  and `error: cannot find symbol class LocationCallback`where findme is my activity